# Protractor/typescript : How to validate and verify downloaded file is '.csv' and verify its contents

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, ui-automation

**scenario::** On clicking Export button, file is downloaded to  Download folder. The name of downloaded file is like 'abc.currentimestamp.csv'.

> Now i have to automate this scenario. I am able to click on button and download the file. But i am facing issue in verifying if file is downloaded or not as everytime i download the file, timestamp is different. If i hardcode the filename in existSync method it works. *This is not proper way to do.*
> I have to make script dynamic so that it will read the latest downloaded file. This is how my code is :

```
browser.driver.wait(function(){ return fs.existsSync(filename.timestamp.csv);},3000).then(function(){
console.log('File Exists!')});
```

> hardocoded method:

```
browser.driver.wait(function(){ return fs.existsSync("C:\\users\\download\\abc.2021-16-6_160045.csv");},3000).then(function(){
console.log('File Exists!')});
```

Comment: Why not save the filename in a variable and then reference it later in `existsSync` call? The name will still be dynamic with the timestamp and won't be hardcoded. If you set the scope of the variable right, it won't interfere with any consecutive specs.

Comment: Another option is to use `fs.stat()`. The returned object will give you access to created and/or modified time for a given file. From there you can sort all files in the directory and then choose the latest downloaded file. This approach will clearly be more complex though but it will work. See [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_filehandle_stat_options) and [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) for more details